# Query : No display on monitor ( VGA CONTROLLER 800*600 resolution ) BASYS 2 BOARD

Tags: verilog

I have created this code for vga controller and the simulation is proper too. The problem is the monitor is blank when code runs, also in the waveform generation the two output's hsync and vsync are displayed '0'. I have no idea where the logic goes wrong. Please help.

Code :

```
module anymodule(input wire clk,reset,
output wire hsynch,vsynch,
output [2:0] red,
output [2:0] green,
output [1:0] blue,
output video_on);


// defining constants
localparam HD = 800; // horizontal display area
localparam HF = 56; // front porch (right border)
localparam HB = 64; //right porch (left border)
localparam HR = 120; // horizontal retrace
localparam VD = 600; // vertical display area
localparam VF = 37; // front porch (bottom border)
localparam VB = 23; // back porch (top border)
localparam VR = 6; // vertical retrace



//horizontal and vertical counter
reg  [9:0] h_count = 0;
reg  [9:0] v_count = 0;
wire [9:0] h_end,v_end;

assign h_end = HD+HF+HR+HB-1;
assign v_end = VD+VF+VR+VB-1;


always @(*) begin
  if(clk)
    if(h_end)
      h_count = 0;
    else
      h_count = h_count+1;
  else
    h_count = h_count;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(h_end) 
     if(v_count<v_end)
       v_count = v_count+1;
     else
       v_count = 0;
  else
    v_count = v_count;
end

assign hsynch   = ((h_count >= HD+HF-1) && (h_count <= HD+HF+HR+HB-1));
assign vsynch   = ((v_count >= VD+VF-1) && (v_count <= VD+VF+VR+VB-1));
assign video_on = ((h_count <  HD)      && (v_count <  VD));

wire [9:0] pixel_x,pixel_y;
assign pixel_x = (video_on)? h_count : 10'b0;
assign pixel_y = (video_on)? v_count : 10'b0;


reg [7:0] coloroutput;

always @(clk)
  if(~video_on)
    coloroutput <= 0;
  else begin
    if( pixel_x<150 && pixel_y<160)
      coloroutput[7:5] <= 3'b111;
    else if(pixel_x<250 && pixel_y<320)
      coloroutput[4:2] <= 3'b111;
    else
      coloroutput[1:0] <= 2'b11;
  end


assign red   = (video_on) ? coloroutput[7:5] : 3'b000;
assign green = (video_on) ? coloroutput[4:2] : 3'b000;
assign blue  = (video_on) ? coloroutput[1:0] : 3'b000;


endmodule
```

Comment: Do you intend `always @(clk)` to be  combinatorial or flip-flop?

Comment: Does the code simulate? does it not work once synthesised, put on an fpga and hooked up to a real monitor? Could you clarify what works and what does not, may be including a testbench.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try simulating this.  I'm pretty sure you'll find that your code doesn't work in simulation.  Always check your code in a simulation environment before trying to program your FPGA!  You have this line:

```
always @(*) begin
  if(clk)
    if(h_end)
      h_count = 0;
```

h_end is a static value, you need to be comparing it to something.  Maybe:

```
if (h_count == h_end)
```

something like that.  Additionally, this always block should tell the tools to look for a rising edge on your clock signal.  E.g.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (h_count == h_end)
```

Comment: Can anybody please provide me with the correct code for vga controller to display a line or a square. I am stuck every now and then and my deadline has arrived too.